# SQL Server "search within group"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have several tables with persons, and need to list all persons which more than one document **and** have a certain document type.

So persons which:

1. have more than one DocumentType, and
2. have one document with DocumentType = 10.

I am getting the names and documents like this:

```
SELECT Name, DocumentType FROM 
(
    SELECT Name, DocumentType FROM SomeTable
      UNION
    SELECT Name, DocumentType FROM SomeOtherTable
      UNION
    SELECT Name, DocumentType FROM YetAnotherTable
) 
GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(Name) > 1
```

And this returns names which have more than one document.

But how can I check if one of the documents has DocumentType = 10?

Comment: What's wrong with `WHERE DocumentType = 10`?

Comment: But then it will only return documents where DocumentType =10, so I won't know if there are other docs? (I think?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can just use a conditional `COUNT` aggregation**

```sql
SELECT Name, DocumentType
FROM 
(
    SELECT Name, DocumentType FROM SomeTable
      UNION ALL
    SELECT Name, DocumentType FROM SomeOtherTable
      UNION ALL
    SELECT Name, DocumentType FROM YetAnotherTable
) t
GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  AND COUNT(CASE WHEN DocumentType = 10 THEN 1 END) = 1  -- or maybe >= 1
```

Notes:

- `UNION ALL` is more efficient as it doesn't remove duplicates. As you are grouping by `Name` afterwards anyway, this does not matter
- You need an alias on the derived table
- `COUNT(Name)` only counts `Name` which is non-null, unclear why you would want this rather than `COUNT(*)`

Answer (score 2):

I suspect what you want here is a conditional aggregate. Also I suspect you want an `UNION ALL` *not* a `UNION`, as otherwise a person with 2 or more of the *same* document but only documents of that type would not be returned:

```sql
SELECT Name,
       DocumentType
FROM (SELECT Name,
             DocumentType
      FROM SomeTable
      UNION ALL
      SELECT Name,
             DocumentType
      FROM SomeOtherTable
      UNION ALL
      SELECT Name,
             DocumentType
      FROM YetAnotherTable) sq
GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(Name) > 1
   AND COUNT(CASE DocumentType WHEN 10 THEN 1 END) >= 1;
```